# Задача про комнаты и печати

Tags: python

Принцип решения мне вроде понятен, но я не знаю как сохранить все входные данные, которые поступают в программу. Особую сложность составляет последовательность чисел, которые записываются в одну строку. Как можно реализовать сохранение всех входных данных для дальнейшей работы с ними? Условие задачи и пример прикрепляю в виде изображения.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я прошу прощения, что мой комментрий - это оффтопик, но я первый раз в жизни увидел, что на codeorces есть задчи на русском языке! мой мир просто встал с головы н ноги...

Comment: [Гугл знает, как получить список чисел из input](https://www.google.com/search?ei=G32VX66zGvKEwPAPzp6AsAY&q=python+список+чисел+из+строки&oq=python+список+чисел+из+строки&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQzQIyBQgAEM0CMgUIABDNAjIFCAAQzQIyBQgAEM0COgQIABBHOgYIIRAKECpQsg1YvxdgkhtoAHABeACAAY4BiAGFApIBAzAuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjurO-h7M_sAhVyAhAIHU4PAGYQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)

Answer (score 1):

более-менее не сложная задача, исключающая по большей части перебор :)

**подсказка:**

раз кол-во печатей чётное, то их всегда можно разбить на пары

**решение:**

пусть есть пара печатей `a1`, `a2` и требуется найти такие `b1`, `b2`, чтобы `a1 * b1 = a2 * b2`

очевидно, что если `b1 = -a2`, а `b2 = a1`, то условие выполняется

поскольку `|a| < 100`, то и `|b| < 100`

или я какое-то из условий пропустил, которое не дает сделать такой подход?

Алгоритм ввода данных можно сделать так:

1. узнать кол-во комнат
2. считать строку с числами для каждой комнаты и распарсить это в массив чисел

Пример код:

```
rooms_amount = int(input())

locks = []

for _ in range(rooms_amount):
    room_locks = list(map(int, input().split()))
    locks.append(room_locks)
```

Ну или в более компактном виде:

```
locks = [[*map(int, input().split())] for _ in range(int(input()))]
```

Comment: Всё верно, вы всё правильно увидели. Это я как раз понял) У меня возникают сложности в сохранении входных данных. Во-первых, я не могу задать определенное количество строк, куда нужно вводить данные, а как это сделать по другому я честно говоря не знаю. И во-вторых, в некоторых строках вводится последовательность чисел, я опять таки не знаю как их сохранить. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @Mswork6, добавил в ответе как это всё можно зачитать у пользователя